# I'm looking for a conversion table for colours in Photoshop/AI/Ind into Microsoft applications

Tags: color, color-conversion, microsoft-office

If colours are selected in Adobe and completely defined in CMYK, RGB, HEX
the (RGB) colours are translated by Microsoft applications into a different colour.

Is there a conversion table from Adobe to Microsoft available to stay true to the original colours?

Comment: You'll have to narrow it down a bit for this question to be answerable. 'Microsoft' and 'Adobe' are both companies that make lots of different software so there are lots of possible combinations. The results that you are already seeing are produced by the built in look up tables which are probably as good as they can be. Generally, this kind of colour management need to be done on a case by case basis so please provide a specific example.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to understand that there may not be an answer to your question in the way you envision it. See a color and numeric value of the color are different things. The numeric value is a device specific instruction, it is literally a different color on every device out there.

Therefore to talking about matching color between two applications is totally meaningless unless 3 other things hold true:

- The output devices used by said applications are calibrated or profiled,
- said application is using a correctly calibrated color management and
- the color space is the same as the original.

If you can ensure those then yes there is a table in the color manager called a ICC profile that can do this (as accurately as possible) for you. And you can ask Photoshop, Illustrator and inDesign do that for you but it makes no sense to do so in most cases.

### MS Office

Since Office applications are not color calibrated and only supports RGB color space there is no way we can even begin to do what you ask. Obviously we can make the color appear the same on **one machine in the universe** by making adobe applications either not color manage, or match the working space with your actual monitor calibration. The former is hardly a useful approach while the later is somewhat useful.

Ok, so all is not lost there is a way, a horrible perilous and totally unfriendly approach but there nonetheless. See the OS is color managed and it does know how to do a color correct workflow trough the printer subsystem.

You can therefore use Adobe Distiller (part of acrobat DC) to make color managed PDF files that then do what you want. **Note**: Its not the act of making PDF that makes it color managed but rather using the Distiller/Printer pathway with a application that knows how to handle colors. So do not use the inbuilt PDF saving routines or other PDF tools, your management will be stripped off.

You can even insert EPS files that are color managed inside Word. These files can then have all the color management in the world up and including CMYK, and Spot colors. Only there is a HUGE caveat you an not rotate or scale pictures inside a word, or the damn application will just rasterize the thing very badly into your document (which is even worse than not doing anything)

### Windows and other apps

Windows does understand color management, but it is up to each application to use the manager. So whether or not any of the things you see are color managed varies case by case basis. Many systems actually just expect you to be sRGB and ignore the rest.

**PS**: Unless your devices are calibrated on spot with a colorimeter then all of this is totally irrelevant. Then the answer is just simply: No.

Comment: >> "You can even insert EPS files that are color managed inside Word"  With old versions of Word, yes, but I'd be cautious about doing this w/o testing first. Recent versions have a built-in PS interpreter (one that's not all that smart) that converts inserted EPS into EMF files; there goes the color management, CMYK gets converted to RGB, etc.  ISTR that there's a registry patch that tells Office to insert EPS graphics the way God and Warnock intended it to be done.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg that's why I warn about moving stuff. It does not trigger if you do not manipulate the image and works fine if you use distiller or postscript printer as target. But its EASY to make it trigger by mistake.

Comment: Interesting ... which version(s) of Word do you use successfully with EPS graphics?  Most of my experience with EPS in Office is with PowerPoint, where unless you make registry adjustments, EPS gets converted to EMF as soon as it's inserted.